# Customize List, View, Edit, New Form for each List

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

I am new at SharePoint, but I have learned that is possible to customize any List Page Form through SharePoint Designer.

However, i noticed that if i have 50 List's Definition in my site i will need to change each AllItems List View Page just to keep them equals, and i know that i wont enjoy this!

What i want to do can not be done with Master Pages.

I realized that there are two files located in the main SharePoint Site, called main.xsl and fldtypes.xsl. Inside one of these files there are the default template for List, Edit, View, Create Forms.

Can i change these files or is better to create my own custom template file and put all my templates there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change default xsl files. You can put fldtypes_youproject.xsl in same folder with specific temlates.

SharePoint automaticly loads fldtypes_*.xsl to XSL rendering engine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff606773.aspx

Comment: Creating a file with fldtypes_*.xsl i don't need to reference  it (using include) in my *Form.aspx? Once i tried to create my custom template files and i couldn't be able to see the Page Preview on SharePoint Designer.

Comment: You should be very careful with fldtypes_*.xsl
Templates in  fldtypes_*.xsl have higher priority than standard templates and you may break all XSL in farm.

Start with MSDN samples.

Comment: Thanks. I read the msdn link that you mentioned, and I didn't find a sample showing how can I create a custom list view template. I just saw some tips about how to create a custom view for a specific field. Do I need to reference my own fldtypes*.xslt using xsl: include or xsl: import?